# Can't get allHeaderFields from NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest with swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

As the response required for `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest` is now requiring `NSURLResponse` not `NSHTTPURLResponse` I can't get `allHeaderFields`.. Is there something I can do here?

```
var newRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: request.URL)
newRequest.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
var response: NSURLResponse
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(newRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: nil)
if response.respondsToSelector(Selector(allHeaderFields)) {
    let allHeaders = response.allHeaderFields
}
```

In the old Objective-C version I was doing this which no longer works in swift..

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[request URL]];
[newRequest setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:newRequest returningResponse:&response error: NULL];
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `respondsToSelector`, you should use optional binding, casting it to a `NSHTTPURLResponse`:

```
let newRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
newRequest.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"

var response: NSURLResponse?
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(newRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: nil)

if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    // use `httpResponse.allHeaderFields`
}
```